# OpenVokaturi - Lock thread

Tags: c, locking

I'm trying to use the Vokaturi API for real-time emotion tracking. I found examples on developers.vokaturi.com. I cannot seem to find out how locking the shared buffer works. My compiler says that 'Lock' is an unknown type.

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiEYA.png)

Comment: Where is lock/unlock defined? Can you post the definition.

Comment: @Jake thank you for your reply. It was not defined, apparently I have to define a lock function myself haha